# Struggling to get images in center in horizontal list view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am struggling to get images to be in center, which are in horizontal list view. As well as I want that images to get equal space(Weight). If I add two images they would take 0.5 weight(Space) of layout each. If I add three they would take 0.33 weight(Space) each.

Below image shows what I get from my code.

[image]

And What I want is like below.

[image]

Below is my codes.

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_back_description"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/txt_app_name"
            android:textSize="35px"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_menu"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_menu_description"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_first"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_second"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_third"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_third"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_fourth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_fourth"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

horizontal_list_view_single_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/single_img_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_list_view_single_img_desc"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Got this result after trying Bunny`s answer.

[image]

Comment: Remove `paddingRight` from your `single_image` and use `layout_weight=1` and `layout_width="0"`. Never use static height width for imageview. Also make `layout_height="wrap_content"` in `com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView`

Comment: Show me the scrrenshot. How you getting now ?

Comment: See I have added image in edit@Bunny

Comment: Have you set `layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"` ? If not please do that.

Comment: Where? in **com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView**@Bunny

Comment: No in `single_image`

Comment: I have added but no difference.@Bunny

Comment: Its already done @Maulik. Tell me is you can scroll to the right most ?

Comment: Yes, But they do not get equal space. i.e each image.@Bunny

Comment: Please see this image - https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wt3se4nvjvhnk8/P0OHH.png?dl=0 The images already getting same size.

Comment: Do you want anything else ? I mean you want to show images differently ?

Comment: I want this horizontal list view at bottom of screen@Bunny

Comment: Then change `layout_weight=1` and set `layout_gravity="bottom"` for your horizontal listview

Comment: And please accept my answer - i think it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank very much for helping, hope this answer solve other`s problem too.@Bunny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `paddingRight` from your `single_image` and use `layout_weight=1` and `layout_width="0"`.Also set `layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"` for `single_image`.  Never use static height width for `imageview`. Also make `layout_height="wrap_content"` in `com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView`

Answer (score 0):

I have created below layout for horizontal list view item and its coming in centre

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/light_black"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Machines" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="100+" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```